# Bash- Find file and insert text in beginning of empty and non-empty files?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, xargs

I am very new to bash commands. Could someone please help me on this issue?

I have to find all .txt files in the current directory and add a text in the beginning of those files. I have written below command-

```
find . -name *.txt | xargs sed -i '1iadd text here'
```

This command works fine for all the non-empty files. But it's not working for those files which are empty. I figured out that it's because the sed command fails to find 1st line in empty files and hence the command is not executed. 
Is there any other way to prepend the text for empty files as well?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a temporary file?

Answer (score 2):

The `ed` Unix text editor can do that.

```
for f in *.txt; do
  printf '%s\n' '0a' 'insert some text here' . w | ed -s "$f"
done
```

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'for f; do printf "%s\n" 0a "insert some text here" . w | ed -s "$f"; done' {} +
```

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' file; do ed -s "$file" <<< $'0a\ninsert some text here\n.\nw\nq'; done
```

Can be done using an `ed` script.

```
cat script.ed
```

Out put

```
0a
insert some text here
.
w
q
```

Now a `for loop`

```
for f in *.txt; do ed -s "$f" < ./script.ed; done
```

Using find.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'ed -s "$1" < ./script.ed' sh {} \;
```

A combination of both.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'for f; do ed -s "$f" < ./script.ed; done' _ {} +
```

- The first line is `1` and the action is `i` (which means insert) in your example which is also true with `ed`, meaning it will not work also with ed because the file is empty and contains no lines, but here I'm using the address as `0` and the action is `a` which means `append`, works.
- The `script.ed` is an arbitrary name and the `./` in `./script.ed` means the current working directory if your `ed` script is somewhere else add/change that to the absolute path of your `ed` script.
- A word of caution, `ed` edit's the files in-place so make sure make a backup of what you're editing just in case...

Comment: Nice to see someone else using `ed` in answers. I'm not alone!

Comment: Yeah. It has some usefulness, you seem to use it with some of your post too.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to improve short oneliners. Sometimes it is good to prepare a typical, self-explaining piece of code, less compact, with some assumptions (here: temporary file), but working in 100% of the cases, e.g:

```
for file in `ls *.txt`; do awk 'BEGIN {print "add text here"}{print$0}' $file > tmp.tmp | mv tmp.tmp $file; done
```

or rather (edited):

```
for file in ./*.txt; do awk 'BEGIN {print "add text here"}{print$0}' "$file" > tmp.tmp | mv tmp.tmp "$file"; done
```

and then to try to mix the solutions.

**EDIT:**

If you have to use `find`, `xargs` and `sed`, and `sed` does not work properly with empty files, you can append an empty line to the file, insert the text, and then delete the appended line:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs -I "%" sh -c 'echo "" >> "%"; sed -i -e "1iadd text here" -e "$ d" "%"'
```

Comment: see [**Bash Pitfalls #1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) for solution #1

Answer (score 0):

Prepend in-place with `ex`:

```
ex -s '+0s/^/add text here/' '+:wq' my_file
```

From stdin to stdout:

```
ex -s '+0s/^/add text here/' '+%print' '+:wq' /dev/stdin
```

Note that this only works with a single file, unlike `sed`.

So for your situation:

```
$ ls
empty  not_empty
$ stat --format '%n: %s' *
empty: 0
not_empty: 6
$ cat empty 
$ cat not_empty 
a
b
c
$ find . -type f | xargs -I '{}' ex -s '+0s/^/add text here/' '+:wq' '{}'
$ cat empty 
add text here
$ cat not_empty 
add text herea
b
c
```

Note that `-I` is used to force xargs to execute `ex` once per file rather than try to aggregate arguments.

And for completeness, a filter from stdin to stdout example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" hello world | ex -s '+0s/^/add text here/' '+%print' '+:wq' /dev/stdin
add text herehello
world
$ cat /dev/null | ex -s '+0s/^/add text here/' '+%print' '+:wq' /dev/stdin
add text here
```